# Mysql delete query deletes only two columns in a row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, delete-row

I have a table with the following structure,

```
    FIELD           TYPE          EXTRA
faciltiy_id         int          auto_increment(Primary Key)
hotel_id            int
facility_title      varchar(20)
facility_desc      varchar(300)
```

When I want to delete a row with a particular `facility_id` I use the code,

```
DELETE 
FROM   $hotel_facilities
WHERE  facilities_id = '$facilities_id'";
```

But instead of the whole row, only the `facility_title` and `facility_desc` fields are getting deleted. If I run this query directly through phpmyadmin over the table it works correctly.

Can anyone enlighten me on what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But instead of the whole row, only the facility_title and facility_desc fields are getting deleted. If I run this query directly through phpmyadmin over the table it works correctly...

Because the `facilities_id` is an INT, you don't need to enclose it within single quotes:

```
DELETE FROM {$hotel_facilities}
 WHERE facilities_id = {$facilities_id}
```

But I think the real issue is that an UPDATE statement is being called, rather than the DELETE statement.  Mainly because a DELETE statement only deletes entire rows, not specific columns.

You need to trace over what is being called when the submit is triggered, and print to screen (either using `echo` or via Javascript if it's more convenient) prior to execution.